# Get key from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm using the flat-cache NPM package and I'm currently blocked because I can't recover the key from the data I'm caching. It must be very simple, but I'm starting with the JS and I'm pulling my hair out on this problem.

Simple example of code :

`main.js`

```
var flatCache = require('flat-cache')
flatCache.setKey('d86f003c-bf0a-4b08-9744-1081c78ece9d', {"creation":"2018/02/20", "link":"https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid","comment":"UUID", "tags":["NPM", "UUID"]});
var a = flatCache.all();
console.log(a);
```

Example of data from console :

```
{
    "d86f003c-bf0a-4b08-9744-1081c78ece9d": {
        "date":"20180220", 
        "comment":"Hello world",
        "tags":[
            "hello", 
            "worlds"
        ]
    }
}
```

What would be the procedure to follow to retrieve the key : d86f003c-bf0a-4b08-9744-1081c78ece9d ?

Thank you in advance for your answer !

Comment: a["d86f003c-bf0a-4b08-9744-1081c78ece9d"]

Comment: Can't you use `flatCache.getKey('d86f003c-bf0a-4b08-9744-1081c78ece9d')` instead of `all()`?

Comment: I wish to obtain the key and not the data associated with the key. Like I made a loop on each element and retrieved the key to set it in an another object or something like this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` method.

In your case:

```
// `a` is defined somewhere there
...
Object.keys(a); // an array of object keys - but only the first level
console.log(Object.keys(a)[0]); // should log `d86f003c-bf0a-4b08-9744-1081c78ece9d`
```

for further reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Ah yes ! That's it, thank you ! I couldn't explain it correctly and so I couldn't find a solution, but thanks to you it's good!